# Save an image opened in a tab using selenium + python in ChromeDriver or GeckoDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I am trying to download images from a website
I have successfully parsed the image source, but it has to be downloaded from the web browser, else it shows

> The server replies that you don't have permissions to download this file.
>   Details: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

So I tried sending Ctrl + S command to the driver, but there is no prompt
So to test my code, I've tried existing code for Opening New Tab, using Ctrl + T command, but even that does not works
Instead of opening a new tab and loading the site, it gets loaded on the same tab

Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com/")

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 't')
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Can somebody provide me any alternative for downloading the image, or sending the save command

Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

ChromeDriver 2.35

FireFox Version 57.0.4 (64-bit)

GeckoDriver v0.19.1

---

**Solution** - Turns out the forbidden access was due to the google reCaptcha
Hence I used a proxy which didnt required solving reCaptcha

Comment: where in here are you trying to get the image? It looks you're going to Google homepage, making two (or three) extra tabs and then going to SO. what site are you trying to get the image from or what are u trying to accomplish? Thx

Comment: I have successfully parsed the link of image from the webpage, using the BeautifulSoup
I cant name the site as it is rated NSFW
for testing purpose just let the image link be

https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png